# LESS disable inherited min-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I use LESS, bootstrap 3 and flat-ui.

I've created a custom button which inherits properties of .btn but I want to get rid of min-width: 120px so this button will act like it does not have min-width value.

That's my base .btn class:

```
.btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

That's my customised btn class where I want to get rid of min-width but it does not work.

```
.btn-user, .btn-user-group {
  .btn;
  .btn-xs;
  min-width: none !important;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border: 1px solid darken(@clouds, 15%);
  background: @clouds;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

How do I get rid of min-width in .btn-user, .btn-user-group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of `min-width` is `0`, not `none` (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp).

Comment: If it works now, please mark this post as "answer" so that the people know that your problem has been solved.

Comment: In 2 minutes because it's still blocked.